# Missing "eclipse-plugin" packaging option

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I' following a [tutorial](http://wiki.eclipse.org/OM2M/Developer#Convert_the_plugin_into_maven_project) which deals with creating a java plugin and converting it to a maven project. One of the steps requires me to right click the plugin, pressing "configure" and selecting the "eclipse-plugin" packaging option:

[image]

The problem is, I don't have the "eclipse-plugin" packaging option:

[image]

Does anybody know why and what I should do to get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to enable Tycho first. Otherwise Maven don't know what a OSGi(=Eclipse) Bundle is. In your case, choose anything as package type (i.e. jar or whatever) and click "Finish". Afterwards edit the pom.xml and change the packaging type to "eclipse-plugin".

Enabling tycho (add this to your parent-pom):

```
   <properties>
      <tycho-version>0.23.1</tycho-version>
   </properties>

   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${tycho-version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
```

See: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Reference_Card

By the way: Since Tycho 0.24.0 it's possible to build plugins/features without a pom (=pomless). If you want to learn more about check this site:

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Release_Notes/0.24